# Cannot install this nuget MauiEssentialsApp.Services in my project .net MAUI

Tags: .net, nuget, maui

It shows this output when I try to install it:

```
Restoring packages for C:\Users\qiqi0\source\repos\AutoCount_V2\AutoCount_V2.csproj...
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
NU1213: The package Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project. 
Package 'Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any 7.0.96' has a package type 'DotnetPlatform' that is not supported by project 'AutoCount_V2'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.3460463
```

Can't install and I'm unable to use  functions like phone dial and email without it. Kindly Advise.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1213

Comment: This is .NET MAUI Essentials runtime pack. You can install the [.NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/).